# Create a condition based on a string and a number

Tags: r

I have a contains 19 columns. But simplified as follows:

```
COMMITTEENAME             DIRECTORS
Cyber                     8
Technology                3
Audit                     12
Cyber Safety              4
Governance                2
```

Now I want to create a third column that gives 1 if there are more than 5 directors and the name of the committee contains Cyber or Technology. So this should be the output:

```
COMMITTEENAME             DIRECTORS            BUSYBOARD
Cyber                     8                    1
Technology                3                    0
Audit                     12                   0
Cyber Safety              4                    0
Governance                2                    0
```

Hope anyone can help me out

Comment: What have you tried so far, and why didn't it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ifelse` option with `grepl` to check if the string got one of the two words:

```r
df <- data.frame(COMMITTEENAME = c("Cyber", "Technology", "Audit", "Cyber Safety", "Governance"),
                 DIRECTORS = c(8,3,12,4,2))

df$BUSYBOARD <- with(df, ifelse(DIRECTORS > 5 & grepl("Cyber|Technology", COMMITTEENAME), 1, 0))
df
#>   COMMITTEENAME DIRECTORS BUSYBOARD
#> 1         Cyber         8         1
#> 2    Technology         3         0
#> 3         Audit        12         0
#> 4  Cyber Safety         4         0
#> 5    Governance         2         0
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>